# Modificar el modelo de usuario de Django

Tags: python, django

Django trae un modelo propio para el manejo de usuarios para inicio de sesión, quisiera saber si este se puede modificar.

La idea es añadir unos campos como tipo de usuario, correo, dependencia, ciudad, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

amigo puedes extenderlo, yo cree algo similar agregando mas campos.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class Usuario(AbstractUser):
    telefono = models.CharField('Télefono', max_length=15)
    avatar = models.ImageField('avatar para tu perfil', upload_to='avatars/', blank=True, null=True)
    fondo = models.ImageField('Elige tu fondo de perfil', upload_to='fondos/', blank=True, null=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
# modelo que sirvio para extender campos a user
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.Usuario'
```

Answer (score 4):

Para guardar información relacionada a tus usuarios, es posible usar un modelo tipo perfil.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    es_astronauta = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Luego, es posible acceder al perfil del usuario como si accedieras a cualquier otro modelo relacionado:

```
>>> usuario = User.objects.get(username='admin')
>>> usuario.pk
1
>>> usuario.perfil.es_astronauta
False
```

Este es el camino más sencillo. Si quisieras tener tu propio modelo de usuario lo que debes hacer es heredar de [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) que contiene toda la implementación del modelo aunque hay algunas consideraciones de diseño que tienes que tener en cuenta. También tienes que implementar tu propio `Manager`.

Si no quieres tocar el comportamiento original del usuario, lo que puedes hacer también es heredar de `AbstractUser` y agregar los campos necesarios aunque el mismo Django recomienda que utilices un modelo separado como el que te he mostrado en la primera parte.

### Referencias

- [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)
- [Specifying a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)
- [Extending Django’s default User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user)