# Cómo migrar del modelo de usuarios de Django a uno personalizado

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy creando una aplicación para un blog personal y después de hacer las primeras migraciones y crear al superusuario, sin ninguna aplicación todavía, se me ocurrió modificar el modelo de usuario, por lo que seguí la la respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8026). Este es mi modelo:

```
# coding: utf-8

import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Ahora bien, procedo a preparar las tablas, creando la migración inicial:

```
manage.py@nspaces > makemigrations users
Migrations for 'users':
  apps/users/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
Following files were affected 
 /Volumes/datos/Proyectos/nspaces/src/apps/users/migrations/0001_initial.py
```

Pero al aplicar la migración, me aparece un error:

```
manage.py@nspaces > migrate
...
# Muchas líneas para trazabilidad que no importan.
...
File "/Volumes/datos/datos_externos/entornos/datos_externos/nspaces/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 298, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

El error dice que la migración de `admin` que es una aplicación del núcleo de Django se aplica **antes** de su dependencia que es `users`.

#### ¿Qué pasos debo dar para migrar del modelo de usuarios de Django a un modelo personalizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta corta es: ***no se puede***.
La respuesta larga es: *Es tan complicado, que no vale el esfuerzo*.

El modelo `User` en Django está relacionado con la *acreditación* y la *autorización* de los usuarios, por lo tanto, involucra relaciones foráneas y relaciones de muchos-a-muchos con tablas del núcleo de Django y no pueden hacerse de forma automática ya que requieren que se modifiquen manualmente los esquemas, moviendo datos de tablas anteriores y con toda seguridad se requiere volver a aplicar algunas migraciones. Hay un [caso abierto](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) en el control de código del proyecto, por si les interesa.

#### Alternativa

Si el proyecto está iniciando, como en mi caso, lo mejor es eliminar la base de datos y la carpeta de migraciones y volver a empezar. Debido a las limitaciones de Django con respecto a las características cambiantes de los modeos, el modelo al que hace referencia `AUTH_USER_MODEL` debe ser creado en **la primera migración de esa app** (por lo general se llama `001_inital`), de otro modo, veremos el error que se presenta en la pregunta.

Hay otros posibles errores, que están [documentados](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) en el sitio de Django.